# Center loader inside div

Tags: html, css

I have this loader:

```
.loader_ajax_small {
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3 !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid #2D2D2D !important;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  -webkit-animation: spin_loader_ajax_small 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin_loader_ajax_small 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin_loader_ajax_small {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin_loader_ajax_small {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

But I can't understand how I can center horizontally inside a div, for example:

[image]

As you can see is on the left but I want it centered, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your loader `margin` to `auto`
something like this

```
margin:10px auto;
```

Answer (score 6):

Added `margin: 0 auto;` in `.loader_ajax_small` for center in parent div

```css
.loader {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
.loader_ajax_small {
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3 !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid #2D2D2D !important;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-animation: spin_loader_ajax_small 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin_loader_ajax_small 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin_loader_ajax_small {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin_loader_ajax_small {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="loader_ajax_small"></div>
</div>
```

or with `display: flex;`

```css
.loader {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;  
}
.loader_ajax_small {
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3 !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid #2D2D2D !important;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  -webkit-animation: spin_loader_ajax_small 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin_loader_ajax_small 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin_loader_ajax_small {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin_loader_ajax_small {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="loader_ajax_small"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvote for showing the FLEX alternative, nice answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin:0 auto;` in `.loader_ajax_small` property.

```css
.loader_ajax_small {
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3 !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid #2D2D2D !important;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  margin:0 auto;
  -webkit-animation: spin_loader_ajax_small 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin_loader_ajax_small 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin_loader_ajax_small {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin_loader_ajax_small {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader_ajax_small"></div>
```